# How do I convert a string to a decimal, and format it for pretty output?

Tags: c#

I want to convert "372551.40" to decimal. But I need to see it after converting this format 372.551,40.

Comment: You wrote in a comment below that your culture is tr-TR. Polishchuk found that this does not include a thousands separator. Do you require a period thousands separator as above?

Comment: I think OP doesn't understand difference between decimal value and string representation of decimal value.

Comment: @Scott, Yes. I send some datas to SAP's web service and it wants decimal value. But when I send a decimal value without commas, SAP does not show the sended datas.

Comment: @cagin, Use my answer. It produces desired formatted string.

Comment: @cagin Use the code in my answer with a German culture (de-DE). I will update the code to suit.

Comment: OK. All done. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: @cagin Did any of these work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert it to decimal, you can use:

```
decimal decimalValue = 0.0;

decimalValue = decimal.Parse("372551.40");
```

or

```
decimal.TryParse("372551.40", out decimalValue);
```

To display it in a specific format you can do:

```
CultureInfo tr = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");    
string formattedValue = decimalValue.ToString("c", tr);
//result will be 372.551,40 YTL

formattedValue = decimalValue.ToString("0,0.00", tr);
//result will be 372.551,40
```

Comment: Consider taking CultureInfo into consideration. =)

Comment: Will do in the future. Thanks.

Comment: I have added culture specific option. I now displays as 372.551,40 YTL

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
string s = "372551.40";
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulure; //Use relevant culture in which your number is formatted. In this case InvariantCulture would do.
decimal d;
bool succesful = Decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Number, cultureInfo, out d); //it will try to parse the string according to the specified culture.;
```

If you have a succesful parse, then `d` will store the numeric value represented by `s` as a `decimal` value which you can output into any formatted string and culture the `ToString()` or `Format.String()`.

Note that if the culture in which the number represented by `s` is the current system culture, then you can use the `TryParse(string s, out decimal d)` overload where it is not necessary to specify `NumberStyles` and `IFormatProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string value;
Decimal number;

value = "16,523,421";
if (!Decimal.TryParse(value,out number))
{
  // set it to something if the "Value" is not a number
  number = -1;
}
```

Comment: @InBetween answer is better cause it takes into account the culture.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
        string s = "372551.40";
        decimal d;
        if (decimal.TryParse(s, out d))
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
            var result = d.ToString("0,0.00", culture);
            // result is "372.551,40"
        }
```

You can also use the current culture instead of hard-coding one like I did.

Hope this helps,

John

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Replace`

```
   string string 1 = "372,551.40";
    string1.Replace(",","");   
    decimalVal = System.Convert.ToDecimal(StringVal);
//shows 372551.40
```

You can always throw that into a for loop if you are playign with a ton of numbers.

You can find more in depth info and some examples on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325121%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I would recommend that you use the features of the System.Globalization namespace rather than direct string manipulation techniques. They would also look after minus and currency symbols for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use [decimal.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse.aspx) to make it a decimal.  Then you have many [formatting options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The display as you mentioned is dependent on the culture setting.

Make your new CultureInfo and in the NumberFormat, you will have to modify some settings like Decimal Separator as `,` and Thousands Separator as `.` and provide this to the `ToString` method of the variable holding the decimal value.

This should display the value as `372.551,40`

Comment: It would be better to choose the correct CultureInfo rather than customizing one.

Answer (score 0):

The overload of [decimal.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6.aspx) that takes an IFormatProvider will allow you to parse strings containing numbers with periods as decimal point symbols (in case the standard is a comma in your culture).

You can use ToString on the resulting decimal to format it with a comma by passing in an appropriate IFormatProvider. Both CulturInfo and NumberFormatInfo implement IFormatProvider.

You can get an instance of [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) with the following code (this one is for English in Australia).

```
new CultureInfo("en-AU")
```

Also note that [decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) is a good alternative to the decimal.Parse method if you expect incorrectly formatted strings as it will allow you to handle them without an exception being raised.

The following code should give you the desired result (you wrote in one of the comments that the target system is SAP and that the culture is probably German (de-DE)).

```
var yourString = "372551.40";
var yourDecimal = decimal.Parse(yourString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var yourFormattedDecimal = yourDecimal.ToString(new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Comment: `var yourFormattedDecimal = yourDecimal.ToString("tr-TR")` will return "tr-TR"

Comment: @polishchuk Thanks for picking that up +1. I have fixed it now.

Comment: After update it doesn't work also. It will return `372551,40`.

Comment: Thanks again +1 (on my mobile and can't test). Added a couple of queries related to the target culture.

Comment: Why do you have to search for a culture which does that, make customize one which suits your need

Comment: The problem with doing that is that these changes will likely only be the start. As soon as you need to format percentages, currencies, dates etc, you will need to make further customizations. There will also be problems if the target culture changes - you will need to supply similar customizations for each new culture. Using standard CultureInfos will mean that you are prepared for other numerical and data types and can support other cultures by simply selecting the appropriate CultureInfo.

Answer (score -1):

From MSDN:

```
string value;
decimal number;
// Parse an integer with thousands separators. 
value = "16,523,421";
number = Decimal.Parse(value);
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' converted to {1}.", value, number);
// Displays: 
//    16,523,421' converted to 16523421.
```

Cheers

Comment: It threw exception. "Input string was not in a correct format." It can be because of my current culture? My culture is tr-TR.

Comment: I guess so. Anyway, take a look at the Parse methods (4 overloads) for the "Decimal" struct.

Comment: @cagin Yes. You could us the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You can create custom `NumberFormatInfo`:

```
string s = "372551.40";
var dec = decimal.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

var res = dec.ToString("n", nfi);
var resDecimal = decimal.Parse(res, nfi);
```

Output is exactly what you need: `372.551,40`

Comment: Yes you are right but I need the value in decimal type. Is it possible?

Comment: @cagin, What do you mean "in decimal type". In my source code `dec` is decimal. `s` and `res` are formatted strings which represent decimal `dec`.

Comment: @cagin, In other words: you format decimal value and result will be string in given format.

Comment: @polishchuck, I mean, res has to be decimal.

Comment: @cagin. No. The commas and decimal points etc are only part of the string representation of the decimal. It is only after you convert the decimal to a string that you will see them.

Comment: @Scott Munro, I think you are right. I can see the correct format when it is a string but when I convert it to decimal, commas are lost.

Comment: The downvote was because of the customization of the CultureInfo. It would be better to select the correct one instead.

Comment: @Scot, Why? I think it more appropriate to create custom, than select. Also it is more readable.

Comment: @polishchuk Check the code at the end of my answer. It was shorter and will also cover other aspects such as minus and currency symbols.